# Restrict network activity in Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm using Cloud Run containers to run untrusted (user-supplied) code. The container receives a POST request, runs the code, and responds with the result. For security reasons, it's deployed on a locked down service account, but I also want to block all other network activity. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run (managed) currently doesn't offer firewall restrictions to selectively block inbound or outbound traffic by IP/host. I'm assuming you're trying to block connections initiated from container to outside. In the future, Cloud Run has plans to add support for Google Cloud VPC Service Controls feature, so that might help.

However, if you have a chance to use Cloud Run for Anthos (on GKE) which has a similar developer experience but runs on Kubernetes clusters, you can actually easily write Kubernetes `NetworkPolicy` policies (which I have some recipes [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes)) to control which sort of traffic can come/go from the containers running. You can also use [GCE firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) and [VPC service controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls) when using a Kubernetes cluster.

Other than that, your only option on a Cloud Run (fully managed) environment is to use Linux `iptables` command while starting your container to block certain network patterns. Importantly, note that Cloud Run (fully managed) runs on a [gVisor](https://gvisor.dev) sandbox which emulates system calls. And many of the features in `iptables`  are currently not implemented/supported in gVisor. By looking at [issue tracker](https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues?q=is%3Aissue+iptables) and [patches](https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues?q=is%3Apull+iptables) , I can tell that it's on the roadmap and some may even be working today.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `iptables` solution? Say I have only one cloud function that's allowed to make requests to the cloud run container. Is there a simple way of using `iptables` to allow outgoing traffic only back to that cloud function? / Is this what you're proposing? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading up on iptables on the internet. Cloud Functions don't run on a static IP, and iptables need to work with IPs. If you make requests to Cloud Functions, there's no way to distinguish these via iptables probably. Though, you can prevent your Cloud Run app to establishing external requests (which is kinda what you said in your question. :))

Answer (score 1):

You could couple the Cloud Run (managed) deployment to a `VPC Network` that doesn't have any internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for my usecase (blocking all egress).

In the first generation of cloud run atlease, there's 2 eth interfaces - eth0 and eth2. Blocking traffic on eth2 solves egress traffic.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth2 -j DROP
```

Run this on startup of the container/app and then ensure the running application is not run (and hence cannot undo this).

Comment: What about on the second generation?